# Why isn't my server sending more than one message?

Tags: python, sockets

When I run the server then the client, the server only sends the first message then nothing. The client still runs waiting for the messages that is not being sent. Any ideas why this is happening?
The is the main function and the mysend and myreceive functions for the client:

```
    def mysend(self, msg):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((serverHost, serverPort))
        s.send(msg.encode())
    
    def myreceive(self):
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.bind((serverHost,serverPort))
            s.listen(5)
            conn,addr=s.accept()
            with conn:
                msg=conn.recv(1024)
                if msg:
                    print ('From Server:', msg.decode())
                else:
                    print('nothing received')
    def main(self):
        msg=PaillierClientSocket.serverHello(self)
        PaillierClientSocket.mysend(self,msg)
        while True:
            PaillierClientSocket.myreceive(self)
            PaillierClientSocket.myreceive(self)
            PaillierClientSocket.myreceive(self)
```

and this is the main, mysend and myreceive functions for the server

```
    def mysend(self, msg):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect(('127.0.0.1', PORT))
        s.send(msg.encode())
    
    def myreceive(self):
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.bind((HOST,PORT))
            s.listen(5)
            conn,addr=s.accept()
            with conn:
                msg=conn.recv(1024)
                if msg:
                    print ('From Client:', msg.decode())
                else:
                    print('nothing was received')
                       
    def main(self):
        PaillierServerSocket.myreceive(self)
        
        msg='105 Key 01, 02'
        PaillierServerSocket.mysend(self,msg)
        
        msg='106 [{ID: 007, Candidate: M M}, {ID: 001, Candidate: M O}]'
        PaillierServerSocket.mysend(self,msg)
        
        msg='107 Polls Open'
        PaillierServerSocket.mysend(self,msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't recreate the socket so much.  Instead, create your sockets in your main(), and pass them - or make them an attribute of a class with a longer lifetime.

EG:

```
def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((serverHost, serverPort))
    # mysends and myreceives go here, passing s to them
```

And then mysend() becomes more like:

```
def mysend(self, s, msg):
    s.send(msg.encode())
```

And be aware of TCP fragmentation and aggregation.  Don't assume that TCP is a message-oriented protocol; it's not.  It's byte oriented - the fact that you can send or receive more than one byte a time is just a performance optimization that confuses some people.

Perhaps try: [https://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/bufsock.html](https://stromberg.dnsalias.org/%7Estrombrg/bufsock.html)
Full Disclosure: I wrote bufsock.